# Maven file path arguments exec

Tags: java, maven, exec-maven-plugin

This is my file structure.

```
├── algs4-data
├── src
│   ├── main
│   └── test
└── target
    ├── classes
    ├── maven-archiver
    ├── surefire
    ├── surefire-reports
    └── test-classes
```

I want to pass the **filename with path** argument and pipe. But I failed, how can I do that?

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="edu.princeton.cs.algs4.BinarySearch" \
   -Dexec.args="algs4-data/tinyW.txt < algs4-data/tinyT.txt"
```

**Update: Log information**

And it only show this and I have to press **Ctrl-C**

```
➜  java_algs4 git:(master) ✗ mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="edu.princeton.cs.algs4.BinarySearch" \
>    -Dexec.args="algs4-data/tinyW.txt < algs4-data/tinyT.txt"
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building algs4 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (default-cli) @ algs4 ---
```

Update 06/15/2016

Thanks Mr.Baumgartner suggestion
I moved data to /src/main/resources

But when I run the code, it gives warning and build failure.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building algs4 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (default-cli) @ algs4 ---
[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:294)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not open algs4-data/tinyW.txt
    at edu.princeton.cs.algs4.In.<init>(In.java:194)
    at edu.princeton.cs.algs4.BinarySearch.main(BinarySearch.java:91)
    ... 6 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.821s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 15 09:29:50 CDT 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/94M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (default-cli) on project algs4: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: Could not open algs4-data/tinyW.txt -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

The update file structure.

```
.
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   │   └── edu
│   │   └── resources
│   │       └── algs4-data
│   └── test
│       └── java
│           └── edu
└── target
    ├── classes
    │   ├── algs4-data
    │   └── edu
    │       └── princeton
    ├── maven-archiver
    ├── site
    │   ├── css
    │   └── images
    │       └── logos
    ├── surefire
    ├── surefire-reports
    └── test-classes
        └── edu
            └── princeton
```

Comment: What was the error message? Can you post your Maven logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your file-structure algs4-data is not visible. When you launch your application, the root of the exection is the target folder. By not putting algs4-data into a src folder like /src/main/resources it wont be copied into the target/classes.

Solution which should work imo without knowing your code nor testing: Copy algs4-data to src/main/resources.

Comment: Thanks, I do your suggestion, but my build fail and I update my question.

Comment: Is algs4-data/tinyW.txt in target/classes?

Comment: Yes (I update the file structure), may be it is because I use **pipe** in the argument?

Comment: Can you put your project on github that i can try to run it?

Comment: Thanks, I put it on git@github.com:yu-yuxuan/algs4_exercise.git   https://github.com/yu-yuxuan/algs4_exercise

Comment: 1.) Move algs4-data back to the root of the project. 2.) Your BinarySearch-Class tries to open a file by a name, your parameter "algs4-data/tinyW.txt < algs4-data/tinyT.txt" is wrong, it's really looking for a file with that name. You can either open tinyT.txt or tinyW.txt, but "<" makes no sense here.

Comment: I want to use pipe so that the **algs4-data/tinyT.txt** can transfer the numbers as standard input.

Comment: No, start from the beginning, think of what a java file oibject does, you can't do shell operations in it.